# Capturing ids by xpath in python from url source

Tags: python, regex, xpath, beautifulsoup

Imagine I have content like:

```
cont="""<a id="test1" class="SSSS" title="DDDD" href="AAAA">EXAMPLE1</a>.....<a id="test2" class="GGGG" title="ZZZZ" href="VVVV">EXAMPLE2</a>....
"""
```

What I want:

```
id1='test1'
id2='test2'
idn='testn'
```

Could you correct me?

```
if '<a id=' in cont:
  ....?
```

Do I have to use **regex** in python or there is a method by **xpath** to grab them?

**Note: I want all ids only in tag a**

Comment: Why aren't u using something like Bsoup or lxml?

Comment: Beautifulsoup seems indeed an easy way to do this: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @Vincent Beltman If you know a reliable method it would be welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download bs4 here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

This should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(cont)
for a in soup.select('a'):  # Or soup.find_all('a') if you prefer
    if a.get('id') is not None:
        print a.get('id')
```

Or with a comprehension to get a list:

```
ids = [a.get('id') for a in BeautifulSoup(cont).select('a') if a.get('id') is not None]
```

Comment: should change html to `cont`. I did:`soup = BeautifulSoup(cont); for ids in soup.find_all('a'): print(ids.get('id'))` and worked as well

Comment: @MortezaLSC but it shows only the value. `test1`, `test2` not `id1='test1'`

Comment: @Avinash Raj, Thank you... No problem I think I should put them into a list and use them

Comment: @Vincent Beltman How can I deny printing None type from list?

Comment: I added:`ids = [a.get('id') for a in BeautifulSoup(cont).select('a') if a.get('id') != None]
print ids
`

Answer (score 1):

Through list comprehension and BeautifulSoup.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> cont="""<a id="test1" class="SSSS" title="DDDD" href="AAAA">EXAMPLE1</a>.....<a id="test2" class="GGGG" title="ZZZZ" href="VVVV">EXAMPLE2</a>....
"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(cont)
>>> [i.get('id') for i in soup.findAll('a') if i.get('id') != None]
['test1', 'test2']
>>> [i['id'] for i in soup.findAll('a') if i['id'] != None]
['test1', 'test2']
```

Comment: But there is a problem...! how can I deny None type of ids ...? and just print test1 and test2?? my result now is:`['test1','None', 'test2', 'None']`

Comment: try this `[i['id'] for i in soup.findAll('a') if i['id'] != 'None']
`

Comment: it returns me error. so I changed it to:`print [i.get('id') for i in soup.findAll('a') if i.get['id'] != 'None']` again error

Comment: post the error. is the result string `None` is included within '' like `None` ?

Comment: This is Error: ` print [i['id'] for i in soup.findAll('a') if i['id'] != 'None']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 892, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'id'`

Comment: You should change it to: `print [i.get('id') for i in soup.findAll('a') if i.get('id') != None]`

Comment: that's what i asked to you previously. is the output you got is exactly `['test1','None', 'test2', 'None']` ?

Comment: Thank you I corrected it... None was correct not 'None'... Pardon me